# Simple pathfinding in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

Does anyone know if there is a simple way to do pathfinding in PHP?

I basically have a list of numbers, e.g.

- `{origin:11485,outboundDirections:"11486,11487,11488"}`
- `{origin:11487,outboundDirections:"11485,11676,94185"}`

and getting from 11485 to 94185 would result in `11485>11487>94185` with ways to "exit", and I'm trying to figure out how to do this (it doesn't really have to be shortest path or anything AI-like, just a way to get from A to B)

I have no idea where to start at all, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read up on either [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for this problem.  These are both well-established (and fairly straightforward) algorithms for finding shortest paths (breadth-first search to minimize the number of hops, Dijkstra's algorithm to minimize the total distance).

Comment: I'm looking at bfs but I can't seem to find any basic class or whatever for it in PHP (I've pretty much only written hello world in it), and I have a couple thousand nodes only. What would be best practice for this? Storing each one in a SQL table with the columns Origin and ExitRoute or give each exit route a column (they aren't consistent and some might have one, some might have five or six)

Comment: How familiar are you with the queue data structure?  If you have not seen this before, I'd recommend looking it up: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(data_structure).  Once you're familiar with this structure, it might be a bit easier to understand how BFS works.  Chances are you're going to have to write it yourself; I don't know of any PHP libraries that do this for you.

Comment: I'm a designer by trade, I have no idea what queueing is. Python instead of PHP might be acceptable too but I have equal amounts of knowledge in both (none). The server I have to work with only has python 2.5, 2.6 and php5/6.

Comment: Also, I should probably add that I'm by no means a PHP/SQL expert.  If someone is more knowledgeable about this than I am, they should probably be able to answer your follow-up question intelligibly. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have recently started and opensourced a flexible pathfinding script in PHP, using the A* algorithm primarily. The idea being to give a node graph object with the most basic methods necessary that the algorithm needs to explore the node graph and get H and G costs.

It would work very easily with your list of numbers since it also uses integers to refer to nodes.

See: https://github.com/Nexii-Malthus/phpPathfinding

Answer (score 0):

If these are similar to a graph the [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) may work.  It is a very basic AI algorithm for games typically but also mazes, navigation, optimal paths.

Comment: He just wants a path, doesn't care about length, so this is overkill.

Comment: True but it is faster than Dijkstra's algo and is one of the most basic pathfinding algorithms around.