# path finding algorithm to find the routes from one place to another

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, algorithm, path-finding

I have 2 table `schedules` and `places`.

My `schedules` table is as follow

```
- Id
- From Place Id
- To Place Id
- Departure Time
- Arrival Time
```

My `places` table is as follow

```
- Id
- Name
```

Eg: When a user searches for routes from `place_id` 5 to `place_id` 1, the system should return an array of routes which contains an array of schedules. That schedule, for example, may look like this

```
[
    {
         from_place_id: 5,
         to_place_id: 3,
         ...
    },
    {
         from_place_id: 3,
         to_place_id: 8,
         ...
    },
    {
         from_place_id: 8,
         to_place_id: 1,
         ...
    },
]
```

I know there are many algorithms like Breadth-First Search, Depth First Search, etc. I have never done them using Laravel eloquent. Please, some give me tips on achieve the results. There are many websites which tell the different algorithms available but none of them explains it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple pathfinding in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609028/simple-pathfinding-in-php) or [How to reconstruct paths from a multi-path Dijkstra](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43901833/689579)

Answer (score 1):

To find path, you have to build graph data structure based on your schedule table. you can fetch all the record from schedule table and build graph from it.

You can use bfs or dfs for this case. But IMO, it's better to use bfs because dfs is not applicable to find shortest path in distance based graph. In case in the future you will apply distance in your schedule table.

You also have to take consideration on departure and arrival time in your schedule data. It means inside your bfs implementation, the departure time of next route of current place cannot less than arrival time of current node.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you give me the code of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

According to what I understand from your question, try this code:

```
$schedules = Schedule::where('from_place_id', '!=', $from_place_id)->where('to_place_id', '!=', $to_place_id)->get();

$roots = Schedule::where('from_place_id', $from_place_id)->get();
$goals = Schedule::where('to_place_id', $to_place_id)->get();

$stack = ['schedules' => []];

foreach ($roots as $root) {
    $travelTime = date('H:i:s', $this->timeDiff($root->departure_time, $root->arrival_time));
    $root['travel_time'] = $travelTime;
    $child = [$root];

    $requiredTime = $this->timeDiff($departure_time, $root->departure_time);

    if ($requiredTime >= 0) {
        foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {
            $previous = $child[count($child) - 1];

            $timeDiff = $this->timeDiff($previous->arrival_time, $schedule->departure_time);

            if ($schedule->from_place_id == $previous->to_place_id &&
        $timeDiff >= 0 && $timeDiff <= 3600) {
                $travelTime = date('H:i:s', $this->timeDiff($schedule->departure_time, $schedule->arrival_time));
                $schedule['travel_time'] = $travelTime;
                array_push($child, $schedule);

                foreach ($goals as $goal) {
                    $goalTimeDiff = $this->timeDiff($schedule->arrival_time, $goal->departure_time);

                    if ($goal->from_place_id == $schedule->to_place_id &&
                    $goalTimeDiff >= 0 && $goalTimeDiff <= 3600) {
                        $travelTime = date('H:i:s', $this->timeDiff($goal->departure_time, $goal->arrival_time));
                        $goal['travel_time'] = $travelTime;
                        array_push($child, $goal);
                        array_push($stack['schedules'], $child);
                        break 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return $stack;
```

Also, you need to create a new protected function for `timeDiff` which looks like this

```
protected function timeDiff($first, $second)
{
    return Carbon::parse($first)->diffInSeconds(Carbon::parse($second), false);
}
```

Don't forget to import `Carbon` and `Schedule` at the top.